# Pycharm says "CSS property 'resize' is not supported by Edge 18, IE 11". Is this a potential problem? Alternatives?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have css applied to a `textarea` and Pycharm says resize is not supported by Edge 18. Is this going to be a problem with Edge browser? I don't know how much I should care about this inspection tbh...

```
    textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: 'resize' property has been fully supported since Edge 79. So, you don't need to care about it if your browser version meets the prerequisite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know this is the only way to do this. [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/css-resize) says that it has 82% coverage. I don't think this will be a problem.

P.S. It is only supported by the webkit browsers